# Pointer to template class as that class parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Basically while trying to implement a graph through adjacency list, I get stucked defining a graph node:

```
template <
    typename Vertex, 
    typename Edge,
    typename EdgeLink = std::pair< Edge, GraphNode* >,
    typename Alloc = std::allocator< EdgeLink >
>
class GraphNode
{
public:
    Vertex vertex;
    std::list< EdgeLink, Alloc > neighbours;
};
```

I realize that I can't give parameters to GraphNode template pointer, because they are not defined yet. My question to c++ templates gurus is: what technique is used in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you use a forward declaration? `class GraphNode;`

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what the question is...  Do you want the GraphNode to have a pointer to another GraphNode with unknown template params..?

Comment: I can't just write GraphNode*, it needs to be
    GraphNode<Vertex, Edge, EdgeLink, Alloc>*
but EdgeLink and Alloc are not defined.

Comment: Does the user really need to specify `EdgeLink` (and the `Allocator`) ?

Comment: EdgeLink is really not necessary, but I want allocator to be template parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Precising the allocator does not necessitate to precise what the allocator can be used for. For example, in a `std::list<T>` the allocator passed is `std::allocator<T>` and yet the `list` will allocate `_ListNode<T>` (implementation defined). This is because allocators need to provide a [`rebind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fk3e8ek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) mechanism.

```
template <
    typename Vertex, 
    typename Edge,
    typename Allocator = std::allocator<void*>
>
class GraphNode
{
public:
    typedef GraphNode<Vertex, Edge, Allocator> NodeType;
    typedef std::pair< Edge, NodeType* > LinkType;
    typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<LinkType>::other AllocatorType;

    Vertex vertex;
    std::list< LinkType, AllocatorType > neighbours;
};
```

In action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/qmYRA).

Note that even though `list` will do a `rebind` itself, you should still do it, because the allocator types `reference` and `pointer` (and their const version) will be pulled as `typedef` inside the `list`.

**EDIT:** Allow container specification.

This is tricky because the allocator is unfortunately only defined once you are within `GraphNode`, you thus need to pass it to the container only within the class, and thus cannot use it in the template outside.

This means using template template parameters, and we thus need to "fix" the arity. Since both `vector` and `list` only take two parameters we are lucky here, but it might not always hold... fortunately with C++11 allowing template aliases, it won't be too harsh a requirement for the user.

```
template <
    typename Vertex, 
    typename Edge,
    template <typename, typename> class Container = std::vector,
    typename Allocator = std::allocator<void*>
>
class GraphNode
{
public:
    typedef GraphNode<Vertex, Edge, Container, Allocator> NodeType;
    typedef std::pair< Edge, NodeType* > LinkType;
    typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<LinkType>::other AllocatorType;
    typedef Container<LinkType, AllocatorType> NeighboursType;

    Vertex vertex;
    NeighboursType neighbours;
};
```

This can be invoked so:

```
GraphNode<std::string, int>
GraphNode<std::string, int, std::list>
GraphNode<std::string, int, std::vector>
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Zn0dX).

Comment: Thanks for the info, it is amazing, the things you can do with template programming!

Comment: Another quick question: how can I use template parameter to specify container, for example to use std::vector instead of std::list?

Comment: @Borzh: updated :) As I said in the answer though, it's trickier than it should because the (proper) allocator only exists within the class.

Answer (score 1):

If your EdgeLink is going to be 'inside' of GraphNode, it's better not to declare it as a template parameter. Instead use this approach:

```
template <
    typename Vertex, 
    typename Edge
>
class GraphNode
{
public:
    typedef GraphNode<Vertex, Edge> NodeType;
    typedef std::pair< Edge, NodeType* > LinkType;
    typedef std::allocator< Linktype > AllocType;
    Vertex vertex;
    std::list< LinkType, AllocType > neighbours;
};
```

Comment: The use of identifiers starting with `_[A-Z]` is forbidden in any scope (reserved to implementation).

Comment: Modified my answer. Thanks for that info :)

Comment: The problem is that I want allocator to be a template parameter. Could you modify the answer in a way to allocator to be a template parameter?

Comment: What information would the 'Edge' type contain? Does it already have information about the two connecting nodes?

Comment: Vertex could be a town name and Edge a number that holds distance from one town to another, for example